# jOOQ update returning clause with Oracle

Tags: oracle, jooq

According to http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/ jOOQ doesn't support returning clause in UPDATE statements for all databases except Firebird and Postgres.

Does anyone know, is this still correct for Oracle with jOOQ? According to Oracle's documentation, Oracle DB fully supports returning clase for DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 1):

#### Incorrect manual

You're right - the manual is wrong and should be fixed:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5470

#### Single row `UPDATE RETURNING`

jOOQ 3.8 added support for single row `UPDATE .. RETURNING` statements. Internally, it uses a `CallableStatement` and a PL/SQL block of the form:

```
begin
  update "MY_TABLE"
  set "MY_TABLE"."COLUMN" = 'XYZ'
  where "MY_TABLE"."ID" = 1
  returning 
    "MY_TABLE"."ID", 
    "MY_TABLE"."COLUMN"
  into ?, ?;
  ? := sql%rowcount;
end;
```

The relevant issue is:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5190

#### Multi row `UPDATE RETURNING`

As of jOOQ 3.8, multi-row `UPDATE .. RETURNING` statements are not yet supported:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5191